# to generate arithmetic test

Tags: php, html, forms

I have written the code in php to generate the test but it has two problems: it does not count the mark and it says it encountered non numeric value. 
I tried casting, is_numeric function still does not work.
I have been on this Q for over a week I know it might be simple for you. Does anyone have an idea to help me ?

These are the errors:

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\TMA.php on line 63
>   
>   Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\TMA.php on line 63
>   
>   Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\TMA.php on line 67
>   
>   Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\TMA.php on line 67
>   
>   Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\TMA.php on line 71
>   
>   Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\TMA.php on line 71
>   
>   Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\TMA.php on line 75
>   
>   Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\TMA.php on line 75
>   
>   Warning: Division by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\TMA.php on line 75

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['start'])) {
    $_POST['add'] = "+";
    $_POST['sub'] = "-";
    $_POST['mul'] = "x";
    $_POST['div'] = "/";
    $num1 = rand(0, 100);
    $num2 = rand(0, 100);
    $num3 = rand(0, 100);
    $num4 = rand(0, 100);
    $num5 = rand(0, 10);
    $num6 = rand(0, 10);
    $num7 = rand(1, 100);
    $num8 = rand(1, 100);

    while($num1 % 10 + $num2 % 10 >= 10) {
        $num1 = rand(0, 100);
        $num2 = rand(0, 100);
    }

    while($num4 % 10 > $num3 % 10 || $num4 > $num3) {
        $num3 = rand(0, 100);
        $num4 = rand(0, 100);

    }

    while($num8 > $num7 || ($num7 % $num8 != 0)) {
        $num7 = rand(1, 100);
        $num8 = rand(1, 100);
    }

    $_POST['o1'] = $num1;
    $_POST['o2'] = $num2;
    $_POST['op1'] = $num3;
    $_POST['op2'] = $num4;
    $_POST['op3'] = $num5;
    $_POST['op4'] = $num6;
    $_POST['op5'] = $num7;
    $_POST['op6'] = $num8;
} else {
    $_POST['o1'] = "";
    $_POST['o2'] = "";
    $_POST['op1'] = "";
    $_POST['op2'] = "";
    $_POST['op3'] = "";
    $_POST['op4'] = "";
    $_POST['op5'] = "";
    $_POST['op6'] = "";
    $_POST['add'] = "";
    $_POST['sub'] = "";
    $_POST['mul'] = "";
    $_POST['div'] = "";

}

$mark = 0;
if(isset($_POST['Mark'])) {

    if(($_POST['o1'] + $_POST['o2'] == ($_POST['ans2'])

           $mark = $mark + 2.5;
        else
            $mark = 0;
    if(($_POST['op1'] - $_POST['op2']) == $_POST['ans2'])
        $mark = $mark + 2.5;
    else
        $mark = 0;
    if(($_POST['op3'] * ($_POST['op4']) == ($_POST['ans3'])
            $mark = $mark + 2.5;
        else
            $mark = 0;
    if(($_POST['op5'] / $_POST['op6']) == $_POST['ans4'])
        $mark = $mark + 2.5;
    else
        $mark = 0;

}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Math Quiz</title>
    <head>
<body>
<h3>Your mark is <?php echo $mark; ?></h3>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <legend><strong><h1 'text-align:center '>Welcome To the math Quiz</h1> </strong></legend>
    </br>
    <label><strong>First Question :</strong></label></br>
    <input type="text" name="o1" value="<?php echo $_POST['o1']; ?>"/> <input type="text" name="add" width="10" value="<?php echo $_POST['add']; ?>"/> <input type="text" name="o2"
                                                                                                                                                              value="<?php echo $_POST['o2']; ?>"/>
    </br>
    <p>Answer :</p>
    <input type="text" name="ans"/>
    </br>
    </br>
    <label><strong>Second Question :</strong></label></br>
    <input type="text" name="op1" value="<?php echo $_POST['op1']; ?>"/> <input type="text" name="sub" value="<?php echo $_POST['sub']; ?>"/> <input type="text" name="op2"
                                                                                                                                                     value="<?php echo $_POST['op2']; ?>"/>
    </br>
    <p>Answer :</p>
    <input type="text" name="ans2"/>
    </br>
    </br>
    <label><strong>Third Question :</strong></label></br>
    <input type="text" name="op3" value="<?php echo $_POST['op3']; ?>"/> <input type="text" name="mul" value="<?php echo $_POST['mul']; ?>"/> <input type="text" name="op4"
                                                                                                                                                     value="<?php echo $_POST['op4']; ?>"/>
    </br>
    <p>Answer :</p>
    <input type="text" name="ans3"/>
    </br>
    </br>
    <label><strong>Fourth Question :</strong></label></br>
    <input type="text" name="op5" value="<?php echo $_POST['op5']; ?>"/> <input type="text" name="div" value="<?php echo $_POST['div']; ?>"/> <input type="text" name="op6"
                                                                                                                                                     value="<?php echo $_POST['op6']; ?>"/>
    </br>
    <p>Answer :</p>
    <input type="text" name="ans4"/>
    </br>
    </br>
    <button type="submit" name="Mark">Mark</button>
    <button type="submit" name="start">Start</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please be specific about exactly what isn't working and what _is_ happening (vs what is expected). If you're getting errors, what is the _exact_ error text? Point out any lines that are throwing errors.  What does "it does not count the mark" mean?

Comment: I see a leaking php code. I just haven't found the reason for the leak. Still looking. =)

Comment: If you press `mark` you clear your `$_POST['op1']` etc. with the `start` function, hereby trying to do math with empty strings, because if `mark` is pressed `start` is not set, and will run its `else` statement

Comment: Or... that is my first guess

Comment: The main problem is actually a bit different. This line `if(($_POST['o1']+$_POST['o2']==($_POST['ans2'])` is missing 2 closing brakets. This line `if(($_POST['op3']*($_POST['op4'])==($_POST['ans3'])` is also missing 2 closing brakets. Also @Stender your guess is correct. As far as i see there are no cheks for empty values during math calculations. Is anyone here aganist me posting a somewhat refined code for this?

Comment: I fixed the brackets still did not counted mark when answer is correct @EugeneAnisiutkin

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin personally I have no problem with you taking my comments into considerations in your answer

Comment: No one know ??:(

Comment: I am working on it)

Comment: you were right the problem is that when I press mark the numbers are lost

Comment: @violet I fixet up your code a bit and posted it as an answer. It's somewhat working now.

Answer (score 0):

My solution may not be the best made code, as it lacks a lot of things like validating fields and so on, but for purely educational purpouses it's pretty easy to understand.

Original code had several proplems: formatting, extra brackets, variable naming, somewhat strange organization of `if else statements`, the mark loosing it's value

Variable naming in general should be better and more unique, as it makes tracking them in code easier, but again for educational purposes i did not make too unique.

Formatting in general can be different, but again in general keeping lines of code short is good practice.

Extra brakets actually comes from formatting a bit and from PHP Operator Precedence. a guide on PHP Operator Precedence can be found [Here](http://tutorialink.com/php/operator-precedence.php). The use of this guide will allow you to get rid of extra brakets somewhat.

I refined organization of if statements a bit, again to make logic more understandable. I saw no need for two separate `if` statements and made one `if`, `else if`, `else` statement instead of it - which realizes the same logic as the original ones.

To resolve the issue of Mark value being lost, i added an **EXTRA** hidden field to form that keeps the current mark value. I also had to add an extra `$_POST` for the same reason. **It is a short term solution sutibale for educational purpouses, but it should work**

I also added some very basic parameter validation. `isset($_POST['op1'])` checks if the answer field `op1` was  filled with something. `is_numeric($_POST['op1'])` checks that the value supplied in `op1` is actually a number.

I fixed the main problems described above and created a workable sample solution.
However the solution laks several important things, which for a beginner can be hard to get.

The code for my solution is:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['start']))
{
    $mark=0;

    $_POST['add']="+";
    $_POST['sub']="-";
    $_POST['mul']="x";
    $_POST['div']="/";
    $num1=rand(0,100);
    $num2=rand(0,100);
    $num3=rand(0,100);
    $num4=rand(0,100);
    $num5=rand(0,10);
    $num6=rand(0,10);
    $num7=rand(1,100);
    $num8=rand(1,100);

    while($num1%10+$num2%10>=10)
    {
        $num1=rand(0,100);
        $num2=rand(0,100);
    }
    while($num4%10>$num3%10 || $num4>$num3)
    {
        $num3=rand(0,100);
        $num4=rand(0,100);
    }  
    while($num8>$num7 || ($num7%$num8!=0))
    {
        $num7=rand(1,100);
        $num8=rand(1,100);
    }
    $_POST['op1']=$num1;
    $_POST['op2']=$num2;
    $_POST['op3']=$num3;
    $_POST['op4']=$num4;
    $_POST['op5']=$num5;
    $_POST['op6']=$num6;
    $_POST['op7']=$num7;
    $_POST['op8']=$num8;
    $_POST['mark']=0;
}
else if(isset($_POST['Mark']))
{   
    $mark=(float)$_POST['mark'];
    if(
        (isset($_POST['op1']) && is_numeric($_POST['op1']))
        && (isset($_POST['op2']) && is_numeric($_POST['op2']))
        && (isset($_POST['op3']) && is_numeric($_POST['op3']))
        && (isset($_POST['op4']) && is_numeric($_POST['op4']))
        && (isset($_POST['op5']) && is_numeric($_POST['op5']))
        && (isset($_POST['op6']) && is_numeric($_POST['op6']))
        && (isset($_POST['op7']) && is_numeric($_POST['op7']))
        && (isset($_POST['op8']) && is_numeric($_POST['op8']))
        && (isset($_POST['ans1']) && is_numeric($_POST['ans1']))
        && (isset($_POST['ans2']) && is_numeric($_POST['ans2']))
        && (isset($_POST['ans3']) && is_numeric($_POST['ans3']))
        && (isset($_POST['ans4']) && is_numeric($_POST['ans4'])))
    {
        if(($_POST['op1']+$_POST['op2'])==$_POST['ans1'])
           $mark=$mark+2.5;
        else
            $mark=0;
        if(($_POST['op3']-$_POST['op4'])==$_POST['ans2'])
            $mark=$mark+2.5;
        else
            $mark=0;
        if(($_POST['op3']*$_POST['op4'])==$_POST['ans3'])
            $mark=$mark+2.5;
        else
            $mark=0;
        if(($_POST['op5']/$_POST['op6'])==$_POST['ans4'])
            $mark=$mark+2.5;
        else
            $mark=0;

    }
    $_POST['mark']=$mark;
}
else 
{
    $_POST['op1']="";
    $_POST['op2']="";
    $_POST['op3']="";
    $_POST['op4']="";
    $_POST['op5']="";
    $_POST['op6']="";
    $_POST['op7']="";
    $_POST['op8']="";
    $_POST['add']="";
    $_POST['sub']="";
    $_POST['mul']="";
    $_POST['div']="";
    $_POST['mark']=0;
}
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple Math Quiz</title>
    <head>
    <body>
        <h3>Your mark is <?php  echo $_POST['mark'];?></h3>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
            <legend><strong><h1 'text-align:center '>Welcome To the math Quiz</h1> </strong></legend>
            </br>
            <label><strong>First Question :</strong></label>
            </br>
            <input type="text" name="op1" value="<?php  echo $_POST['op1']; ?>"/>
            <input type="text" name="add" width="10" value="<?php echo $_POST['add']; ?>"/>
            <input type="text" name="op2" value="<?php  echo $_POST['op2']; ?>"/>
            </br>
            <p>Answer :</p>
            <input type="text" name="ans1" />
            </br>
            </br>
            <label><strong>Second Question :</strong></label></br>
            <input type="text" name="op3" value="<?php  echo $_POST['op3']; ?>"/>
            <input type="text" name="sub" value="<?php  echo $_POST['sub']; ?>"/>
            <input type="text" name="op4" value="<?php  echo $_POST['op4']; ?>"/>
            </br>
            <p>Answer :</p>
            <input type="text" name="ans2" />
            </br>
            </br>
            <label><strong>Third Question :</strong></label></br>
            <input type="text" name="op5" value="<?php  echo $_POST['op5']; ?>"/>
            <input type="text" name="mul" value="<?php  echo $_POST['mul']; ?>"/>
            <input type="text" name="op6" value="<?php  echo $_POST['op6']; ?>"/>
            </br>
            <p>Answer :</p>
            <input type="text" name="ans3" />
            </br>
            </br>
            <label><strong>Fourth Question :</strong></label></br>
            <input type="text" name="op7" value="<?php  echo $_POST['op7']; ?>"/>
            <input type="text" name="div" value="<?php  echo$_POST['div']; ?>"/>
            <input type="text" name="op8" value="<?php  echo $_POST['op8']; ?>"/>
            </br>
            <p>Answer :</p>
            <input type="text" name="ans4" />
            </br>
            </br>
            <input type="hidden" name="mark" value="<?php  echo $_POST['mark']; ?>" />
            <button type="submit" id="Mark" name="Mark">Mark</button>
            <button type="submit" name="start">Start</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the problem still there the mark does not increase when answer is right

Comment: =D Totaslly forgot about `$mark` var and the problem with it. Fix is coming

Comment: thanks a lot it is really hard for me as a beginner in this language and in programming generally to find errors

Comment: @violet I made a quick fix for the code and updated the answer. Be carefull though, it's only suitable for educational purpouses.

Comment: @violet My bad, forgot some checks, sorry, tired. It should work right now. at least as an exaple it is functional

Comment: I'm sorry but it still  not working and an (int) and (float) words showed up !!

Comment: @violet Thats debug info - does not effect the work of the test. Removed debug info

Comment: It worked yay! the problem is that you made the conditions for the answers to be answered all to count the mark , but this not the case in my Q I forgot to mention it anyway thank you so much :)

Comment: It worked for two minutes then stoped . I'm talking about the mark var